# Regex does not properly break down file path with a version number

Tags: java, regex, file, path, version

I was using a regex pattern to break down the context path for a servlet.

```
/{1,2}([^/{1,2}]+)
```

This works great for simple paths like `/User/folder1/folder2/folder3/`.

In more real world scenario however there seems to be a problem if one of the folder names contains a dotted version number, such as: `/User/username/Library/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.24`.

In this case `Matcher.group(1)` will return `apache-tomcat-6.0.` instead of `apache-tomcat-6.0.24`. I don't know why that happens; I believe it should not.

Any insights?

**Edit**

This works:

```
/{1,2}([^/]+)
```

Comment: In .NET {x,y} means match x to y occurrences of the last token. Also, you would write it after the [...] clause. What does these mean in java? Also, aren't there any String.Split you could use, to split on /?

Comment: @Philip pretty much answered it. I need to remember to only use the range quantifier expression outside of character classes. My bad. I could also use string split but I also want to use this in another regex pattern for xpath expressions in order to seperate namespace from predicate. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[^/{1,2}]` means "every character except `/`, `{`, `1`, `,`, `2` and `}`", so the `2` of `24` doesn't get matched (it will be the same with a path like `a/2` and is unrelated to version numbers). Inside `[…]`, most characters are interpreted literally, and constructs such as `{1,2}` don't work. I think it should work if you simply say `[^/]+` instead. I'm not sure why you want to match two consecutive slashes anyway—simply match a single slash and filter out empty directory names.

Comment: Alright, thanks. The reason why I want to match double slashes is because I also want to use this regex for xpath expressions, in which `//` is an abbreviation for any descendant element.